# Initialize Database Context (Domain Layer) in Presentation Layer, via Business Layer

Tags: asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-core

I am a quite new programmer and have an ASP.NET Core Web application. It all worked fine, until I noticed I needed layers (Business, Domain and Presentation) as I understood this is a best practice. Due to the creation of these layers questions arise.

In my startup, I have a configuration method for initializing of the database. However, as the DishInfoContext class is now in the Domain project, it should not be accessed directly from the Presentation project anymore.

I tried creating a class and method in the Business layer to inject the DishInfoContext, but it does not work.

Configuration method in Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        string connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=DishesDB;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
        services.AddDbContext<DishInfoContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

        // So, here I guess DishInfoContext should be replaced with something else?

        services.AddScoped<IDishService, DishService>();
    }
```

DishInfoContext class:

```
namespace MyDishesApp.Domain.Entities
{
public class DishInfoContext : DbContext
{
    public DishInfoContext(DbContextOptions<DishInfoContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.Migrate();
    }

    public DbSet<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
}
```

What should I do to pass the DishInfoContext via the business layer to the presentation layer? Or should I try another method?

I hope I am specific enough, thanks for the help!

PS: I also created services for my repositories in the business layer, as the repositories are in the domain layer.

Answer (score 3):

You fell into the trap of following "advice" you don't understand. This is common for new developers, as there's an innate desire to do things "right", but you don't yet understand what that means or entails.

First, what you're doing here is call N-Tier, and while it's been a staple of software development for decades, it's no always the right choice. In particular, if you're not used to the pattern and your application doesn't actually *need* it, then you can end up introducing serious problems and inefficiencies into your application.

You need to realize that there is no true separation to be had here. Your web app (what you're referring to as the presentation layer), requires a database connection. As a result, there's a hard dependency here. The most you can hope for is to abstract the majority of the code that accesses the database, but you *still* will need to depend on something you can use in your controllers to get data. The typical approach here is to implement a repository/unit of work pattern. That then becomes your data layer. However, what most people miss is that if you're using EF, *that* is your data layer. Data access is already abstracted, so your app simply has a depedency on EF, instead of some custom class library you create. EF is an ORM, and as such *already* implements the repository/unit of work patterns.

Long and short, just use your EF context directly in your web app. If your app eventually grows large/complicated enough to warrant abstracting that away, you should consider either the microservice or the CQRS patterns. However, both are non-trivial and are easily overkill for a simple app.

The best advice I can give you is to simply build your app. Don't worry about patterns or what other people say. Your app dictates what patterns or architectural styles should be employed, not the other way around. When you start doing stuff because you "supposed to", that's when your app goes off the rails. The goal of all of this is clean, documented, and easily maintainable code. If you have that with a single layer, then you don't need anything else.

Comment: Perfect answer / advice!

Comment: Allright, thanks for the advice! 
My question arose as I created dto's, entities and viewmodels. So, I was wondering why I need all three and why I should map from viewmodel to dto and from dto to entity. 
I heard this is quite normal, but it is used with distinct layers with business logic.

I guess I should map from viewmodel to entity directly then? And just skip the dto? The app is for learning purposes only, so I thought by introducing these layers I would make the most out of it.

Comment: Entities, view models, DTOs: they're all just object representations. You add one when you have a different domain. Entities belong to the database, and thus have a very specific set of concerns. These concerns can and often will be different that what you need for your view; thus, a view model is created. Since all you're doing here is passing data back and forth between the database and views, yes, that's all you need.